# According to Gauss's theorem the integral of $\vec \nabla⋅(\phi \vec E)$ taken over the whole space is equal to 0?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, integration, vector-fields, boundary-conditions

The following excerpt is from [Space—Time—Matter by Hermann Weyl](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/43006), starting on page 101.  Among the things I'm not understanding is Weyl's assertion that the integral of $\nabla\cdot(\phi\mathbf{E})$ vanishes due to Gauss's theorem.  **Why should I believe that?**

The potential $\phi$ is defined by $\mathbf{E}=\nabla\phi.$  I've noticed the current German language edition has some of the signs reversed, so that might correctly be $-\phi.$  But I don't think that matters for my question.

> A system of discrete point-charges $e_{1}, e_{2}, e_{3},\dots,$ has potential
> energy
> $$
> U = \frac{1}{8\pi} \sum_{i \neq k} \frac{e_{i} e_{k}}{r_{ik}}
> $$
> in which $r_{ik}$ denotes the distance between the two charges $e_{i}$ and $e_{k}$.
> This signifies that the virtual work which is performed by the
> forces acting at the separate points (owing to the charges at the
> remaining points) for an infinitesimal displacement of the points
> is a total differential, viz. $\delta U$. For continuously distributed charges
> this formula resolves into
> $$
> U = \iint \frac{\rho(P) \rho(P')}{8\pi r_{PP'}}\, dV\, dV'
> $$
> in which both volume integrations with respect to $P$ and $P'$ are to
> be taken over the whole space, and $r_{PP'}$ denotes the distance between
> these two points. Using the potential $\phi$ we may write
> $$
> U = -\tfrac{1}{2} \int \rho\phi\, dV.
> $$
> The integrand is $\phi \nabla\cdot\mathbf{E}$. In consequence of the equation
> $$
> \nabla\cdot(\phi\mathbf{E}) = \phi \nabla\cdot\mathbf{E} + \mathbf{E}\cdot \nabla\phi
> $$
> and of **Gauss's theorem, according to which the integral of $\nabla\cdot(\phi\mathbf{E})$
> taken over the whole space is equal to $0$,** we have
> $$
> -\int \rho\phi\, dV = \int (\mathbf{E} \cdot\nabla\phi)\, dV
>   = \int |E|^{2}\, dV;
> $$
> i.e.
> $$
> U = \int \frac{1}{2} \left|\mathbf{E}\right|^{2} dV .
> $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gauss's theorem is another name for the divergence theorem, which says that if you have some region $M$ with boundary $\partial M$ then

$$\int_M \mathrm{div}(\mathbf F) \mathrm dV = \oint_{\partial M} \mathbf F \cdot \mathrm d\mathbf S$$

Let $M$ be a ball of radius R centered at the origin.  We would then have that

$$\int_{|\mathbf r|<R} \mathrm{div}(\mathbf F) \mathrm dV = \oint_{|\mathbf r|= R} \mathbf F \cdot \mathrm d\mathbf S  \leq 4\pi R^2 \cdot \sup_{|\mathbf r|=R}|\mathbf F(\mathbf r)|$$

As a result, if $|\mathbf F(\mathbf r)|\rightarrow 0$ faster than $1/|\mathbf r|^2$ as $|\mathbf r|\rightarrow \infty$, then we can take the limit as $R\rightarrow \infty$ (thereby integrating over all space) to obtain
$$\int_{\mathbb R^3} \mathrm{div}(\mathbf F) \mathrm dV = 0$$

All that remains is to show that this is true for $\phi \mathbf E$. As long as the number of point charges in question is finite, then this is not difficult to see (in the limit of large $R$, $\phi \mathbf E \sim R^{-3}$).

Comment: Does this require the system under examination to be bounded in space?  IOW, I can speak of points "infinitely" far from every component of the system?

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton If you have a finite collection of point charges, then each of them has to be *somewhere* (i.e. at some point of $\mathbb R^3$), which means that the collection as a whole occupies a bounded region of space. If you have an infinite collection of point charges this is no longer true, and this procedure generally fails.

Comment: I have come to believe that this is not what Weyl intended.  In particular he is considering a continuous distribution of charge; as opposed to point charges.  It's hard to know what he considers to be contained in "all of space", beyond the assumption that the net charge of the Universe is zero.

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton If you wish to consider a continuous distribution of charge, then that's also fine as long as the distribution is either confined to a compact region of space, or decreases in magnitude sufficiently rapidly (e.g. exponentially) as $|\mathbf r|\rightarrow \infty$) that the RHS of my second equation goes to zero. Other than that, the answer does not appreciably change.

Comment: The expression *continuously distributed charges.*  Weyl seems to be vacillating between the 19th and 20th century models.   In the 1922 Edition, Weyl adds another paragraph in which he explicitly speaks of "unendlichkleine Ladung $\delta e$".  His equations for the laws of electrostatics are differential in form.  That supposes a continuous charge distribution.  When dealing with elasticity at the scale of structural engineering, ignoring the atomicity  of mater is acceptable.  But it cannot be carried over to fundamental laws of Nature.  Weyl does not address this problem.

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton If you allow the charge densities $\rho$ to be distribution-valued, then you may let $\rho(\mathbf r) = \sum_{i=1}^N q_i \delta(\mathbf r-\mathbf r_i)$ and recover the discrete expression. The laws of electromagnetism are agnostic as to the discrete or continuous nature of the charges and currents which act as sources; I fail to see the problem beyond the usual infinities which arise when dealing with singular point charges, and which are ultimately resolved via renormalization.

Comment: "We would like now to discuss how it might be possible to modify Maxwell’s theory of electrodynamics so that the idea of an electron as a simple point charge could be maintained. Many attempts have been made, and some of the theories were even able to arrange things so that all the electron mass was electromagnetic. But all of these theories have died." https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_28.html#Ch28-S5

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton Right. The resolution comes with the renormalization which occurs in QED, in which the electron is *not* a simple point charge.

Answer (score 0):

The physical meaning for that, I'm not sure if this is something you already know, there is no potential difference at the same surface.
There's potential difference between one surface and another, but at the same surface the potential difference is zero, and this is what we call an equipotential surface.
The definition of an equipotential surface is a surface composed of all those points having the same value of potential.
So, there is no potential difference between any two points on this surface. therefore, No work is involved in
moving a unit charge around on an equipotential surface, or any closed path.

Comment: The integrand under discussion isn't a "standard" potential.  It is the product of the electric potential and the electric field.  $\nabla\cdot(\phi\mathbf{E}).$  That's what threw me for a loop.